# R: Why won't a formula produced using paste() work with model.matrix()?

Tags: r, model

Edit:  This has been answered.  All I needed to do was coerce the pasted text to a formula using as.formula().

I have been trying to pass formula created using a paste command to `model.matrix()`.

It works fine when I use:

```
mm <- model.matrix(~ V1+V2+V3+V4, data = mode_set)
```

It also works if I use a vector of variable names and a paste function:

```
varlist <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")

mm <- model.matrix(paste("~ ",paste(varlist, collapse="+"),sep = ""))
```

However, if I save the output from the `paste()` function to another variable, and pass that to `model.matrix()` I get a `$` operator atomic vector error.

```
form <- paste("~ ",paste(varlist, collapse="+"),sep = "")
mm <- model.matrix(form, data=model_set)
```

It also fails if I remove the quotes from the pasted variable name:

```
form <- noquote(paste("~ ",paste(varlist, collapse="+"),sep = ""))
```

Formulas made in this way are fine when passed to the models I've been using (GLM, earth, randomForest, rpart etc.) - why doesn't `model.matrix` like them?

Comment: which is to say, use `as.formula(paste(...))`

Comment: Thank you!   That's sorted it out immediately!

Comment: Note that `reformulate` is built to produce such things: `reformulate(c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"))`, for example.